# OpenApi OpenApiResponseWithBody throws error when using typeof

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, swagger-ui, openapi

I have the following OpenApi annotations for my azure function:

```
        using Hl7.Fhir.Model;

        [FunctionName("FunctionName")]
        [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "OpId", tags: new[] { "Tag" }, Description = "Description to be filled.")]
        [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
        [OpenApiRequestBody("text/json", typeof(ProjectModel), Required = true)]
        [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "GpName")]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, bodyType: typeof(ClassLibraryModel), contentType: "application/json", Description = "The OK response")]

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "v1.1/apiendpoint")] HttpRequest req,
           ILogger log)
        { }
```

In `[OpenApiResponseWithBody]` if I use `typeof` with the Model that is in the project itself, swagger UI shows up without any issues.  But when I use a different model which is imported at the top using the using statement `using Hl7.Fhir.Model`, the app just crashes.  Any ideas why that is happening? Any help would be appreciated.

There are no exception details, the app simply crashes.

Comment: Have you tried using `application/json` instead of `text/json`. Also, are there any circular references in your model? can you provide your model?

Answer (score 0):

I am following this [Document](https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-NET-SDK/model/multiple-fhir-versions.html).

I am adding `Hl7.Fhir.STU3` & `Hl7.Fhir.R4` packages in azure function and am using **FHIR** version **STU3** and **R4** simultaneously. So adding aliases of `STU3` & `R4` packages. So that we can differentiate which package can use Patient.

> Eg: STU3 using Patient as well as R4 using Patient

```
< ItemGroup>
    < PackageReference Include="Hl7.Fhir.STU3" Version="3.0.0" />
    < PackageReference Include="Hl7.Fhir.R4" Version="3.0.0" />
< /ItemGroup>

< Target Name="AddPackageAliases" BeforeTargets="ResolveReferences" Outputs="%(PackageReference.Identity)">
    < ItemGroup>
    < ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)'=='Hl7.Fhir.STU3.Core'">
        < Aliases>stu3< /Aliases>
    < /ReferencePath>
    < ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)'=='Hl7.Fhir.R4.Core'">
        < Aliases>r4< /Aliases>
    < /ReferencePath>
    < /ItemGroup>
< /Target>
```

[image]

I am able to run and get the information of azure function
[image]